# Bad certificate name causes Security Sandbox Violation Error in Adobe Flash movie

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm testing the communication of my Adobe Flash app to the server using **HTTPS**.

If I make the request to `https://localhost` everything's fine. But if the request url is set to `https://192.168.0.1` the URLLoader fails with this Stream error:

```
Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://192.168.0.1/path-to-script/
```

If i call the URL in the browser I get a security warning, which I can override (in Chrome):

```
This is probably not the site you are looking for!
[Proceed anyways]   [Back to safety]
```

Of course that's because the certificate's name ("localhost") doesn't match the IP address.

Now, is it possible to ignore/suppress that warning/error? e.g. is it possible if I would use the flash.net.Socket class?

---

**UPDATE**

I did more thoroughly tests now.

The **crossdomain.xml** I'm **already** using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"  />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**Working** scenario:

Flash hosted on and loaded from `http://www.domain-A.com`
URLLoader request to `https://www.domain-B.com/demo.html`

**Not working:**

Flash still hosted and loaded from `http://www.domain-A.com`
URLLoader request to `https://{IP_OF_SERVER}/demo.html`

The problem is, that Flash doesn't even load the `crossdomain.xml` because of the "bad certificate name" error. (Caused by the fact, that the certificate is issued for `www.domain-B.com`, not for a IP adress)

**The specific error message:**

> ***** Security Sandbox Violation *****
> Request for resource at https://{IP_OF_SERVER}/demo.html by requestor from http://www.domain-A.com/flash/demo.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.

**To get an idea what happens:**

Open https://65.54.186.107/ in your browser (it's the IP of https://login.live.com)
To get to the website you have to acknowledge/ignore the warning.
"This is probably not the site you are looking for!" in Google Chrome
"This Connection is Untrusted" in Firefox
"There is a problem with this website's security certificate." in IE
...

I'm looking for a way to "ignore" this warning in Flash.

**Conclusion**

If there's no way to tell Flash to ignore SSL "bad certificate name" errors, I can only think of digging into the [flash.net.Socket](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html) class.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to the conclusion, that it can't be solved. The certificate name **must** match the domain name, otherwise the communication will fail.

After all, it's a security measure. (Compare: there's also no way for a website to tell the browser to override the security warning.)

Only if Adobe would also implement such security warning (in a future version of Flash) and let the user decide whether or not to proceed, the certificate could be issued to another domain name.

If you must use an IP address instead of the domain name you might consider buying a certificate issued to the IP address instead of the domain name: http://www.ssl247.com/ssl-certificates/type/ip-address

Answer (score 2):

Its all about domain.
https://localhost and https://192.168.0.1 are not the same domain.
You would have to configure your crossdomain policy to accept localhost.

[EDIT]
Try this on the https server

```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE
> cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
> "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
> <cross-domain-policy>
>     <allow-access-from domain="www.company.com"
> secure="false" />  
> </cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately that's not the issue. See my updated question.

Comment: are you dishing out the crossdomain file on the https server or the http?

Comment: "is denied due to lack of policy file permissions" is completely a crossdomain issue

Comment: The domains (for testing) are all pointing to the same www root. So the crossdomain.xml is available over http and https.

Comment: It's not a crossdomain issue, because Flash cannot access the crossdomain.xml. Nevertheless the file is there. But because of the certificate error, Flash doesn't even load the crossdomain.xml.

Comment: e.g. try this: open https://65.54.186.107/ in your browser and see what happens. You'll get a warning. Don't worry it's just https://login.live.com. Just that Flash apparently doesn't give you the option to ignore those warnings.

Comment: AAAh I see. Yeah, The cert is only good for the domain. You can't use the same the cert on the IP so you would have to get a different cert for that. As far as the socket idea it could be done, but unless you encrypt the data going over the socket you are defeating the purpose of using ssl in the first place.

Comment: I edited my answer can you try it on your https server. I am still not sold 100% that this is a certificate problem.

Comment: also force it to load the file Security.allowDomain("www.company.com");

Comment: The cert is fully signed, and allowDomain didn't help either. Because I don't have the time to investigate how to implement TLSSocket we just changed the URL back to the domain name (instead of the IP). But if somebody knows how to implement it with TLSSocket (if it's even possible to override the SSL error) I'ld be more than happy to see it. Anyways, thanks @Tha_asMan for your efforts.

Comment: Did you try to make it a trusted site on the browser?

Comment: Actually I can't remember anymore. I can only guess that I tried something like that. But (obviously) that wouldn't have been a solution anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The_asMan is right you need a crossdomain policy if you're accessing a swf on another domain from within your main swf or a swf on your primary domain. But I think the issue here is that you're trying to establish a connection to the server through your router or gateway IP and that will not work in this case. If it were working properly within flash and it was just a security error, then you would expect to see a security sandbox violation error, not a stream error (unable to establish connection). Test with your local address and if you want to test on another server then upload it to a web server or something but trying to use your gateway address just doesn't make sense and probably doesn't work. If you're running a server like Xampp on your local machine and testing with the localhost address, you're doing this accurately and can expect your application to function the same deployed on a web server.

Here's some NFO on that error that is in line with what I'm saying:

http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/

Comment: Thx. I did my last tests now on a local server for both domains, using custom host names (added to hosts file in windows). See my updated question.